# Error trying to parse repeat characters with pyparsing

Tags: python-3.x, pyparsing

I am getting unexpected behavior while trying to parse some text with pyparsing. I am parsing some semi-structured text line by line, and one of the possible lines is a record separator that consists of an entire line of '=' characters like so:

'=================================================='

It is also possible to have a blank line at this point, so I have to try both options. If I try to parse a line that consists only of white space using the following definition(assumes `import pyparsing as pp`): `pp.Word('=', min=10)`, I get an `IndexError: string index out of range` error instead of the expected pyparsing exception for a not-match. The definition `pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word('='))` has the expected behavior, so I will of course use this in my code. My understanding is that these definitions should be equivalent in this case, and pyparsing should return a ParseException instead of IndexError. Am I missing something?

```py
import unittest
import pyparsing as pp


class Test(unittest.TestCase):


    def testSepDetail(self):
        verbose = True
        pattern1 = pp.Word('=', min=10) # Throws IndexError: string index out of range
        pattern2 = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word('=')) # Works as expected
        testPattern = pattern1
        testList = [
('=======================','======================='),
('     ',None)]
        for test in testList:
            text, expected = test
            result = self.harness2(testPattern, text, expected, verbose)

    def harness2(self,pattern, text, expected, verbose):
        '''
        '''

        if verbose:
            print('\n---Test for: {0}'.format(text))
        try:
            result = pattern.parseString(text)
            if verbose:
                print('Parse successful.\n', result.dump())
            if expected:
                self.assertEqual(expected, result[0], "\n\tParse Successful, but data not as expected.\n\tExpected {0}\n\t but got {1}".format(expected, result[0]))
            return result          
        except pp.ParseException as x:
            failmsg = "\n---Failed to parse string: {0}\n{1}".format(text,str(x))
            print(failmsg)
            self.fail(failmsg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #import sys;sys.argv = ['', 'Test.testName']
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, this is with pyparsing 2.0.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an error on your part, it is a bug in pyparsing, the result of re-optimizing code after forgetting that it was previously optimized in a conflicting fashion. This issue actually affects several of the pyparsing classes, not just Word (primarily those that subclass from pyparsing's Token class).

In practice this not so much of an issue, as Token-type expressions are rarely used in isolation, and the container expressions such as OneOrMore, etc. all trap for IndexError and reraise ParseException.

For instance, these will also work around the IndexError problem in Word:

```
pattern2 = pp.empty + pp.Word('=')
pattern2 = 1*pp.Word('=')
```

I will definitely clean this up for the next release, but in your application, I think things will work fine if you change your handler to:

```
except (pp.ParseException, IndexError) as x:
```

Then when you upgrade to the fixed version, you only have to change the one except statement instead of all the places in your grammar that you hacked with OneOrMore.

Note: you can also make your test bench tolerant of exception cases if you change the `self.fail` call to:

```
        if expected is not None:
            self.fail(failmsg)
```

Comment: Thanks for your exceptionally prompt answer! And your exceptional software. It has really made my life easier.